# Add file to git confirmation

Tags: git, android-studio

I am newbie and trying to play git in Android Studio. Before, everytime i create new file in Android Studio, it offers me to add the new file to git. But now it's no longer. I have search on google but no result i found. How to fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the Settings dialog, under Version Control | Confirmation, please ensure that "Show options before adding to version control" is enabled under "When files are created".

Comment: where is Confirmation?